# Archive/zip read file.zip: bad file descriptor

Tags: file, go, zip

I have written a function to read zip archive to`map[string]*zip.File`.

```
func ReadZip(file string) (map[string]*zip.File, error) {
    r, err := zip.OpenReader(file)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer r.Close()
    files := make(map[string]*zip.File)
    for _, f := range r.File {
        files[f.Name] = f
    }
    return files, nil
}
```

But when i try to open file `infoRC, err := f["info.json"].Open()` arises error

> read file.zip: bad file descriptor.

Is there better way to read zip archive?

Comment: Once `r.Close` is called, any of the `*zip.File` structs are invalid. You need to either  (a) keep `r` open as long as you want to read the ZIP entries, or (b) make an in-memory/temporary file copy of all of the zip file contents.

Comment: Thanks! Please write that as a answer. @TimCooper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once [`ReadCloser.Close`](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#ReadCloser.Close) is called, any of the `*zip.File` structs are invalid:

> Close closes the Zip file, rendering it unusable for I/O.

You need to either:

1. Keep `r` open as long as you want to read the ZIP entries, or
2. make an in-memory/temporary file copy of all of the zip file contents

An example of the latter option:

```
func ReadZip(file string) (map[string][]byte, error) {
    r, err := zip.OpenReader(file)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer r.Close()
    files := make(map[string][]byte)
    for _, f := range r.File {
        fc, err := f.Open()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(fc)
        fc.Close()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        files[f.Name] = contents
    }
    return files, nil
}
```